# Calculate difference between one column over multiple rows using coalesce and join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table

```
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id  | job_id | source_id | target_id | value |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| 204 |   5283 |       247 |       228 |  1201 |
| 349 |   4006 |       247 |       228 |   100 |
| 350 |   4007 |       247 |       228 |   500 |
| 351 |   4008 |       247 |       228 |  1000 |
| 352 |   4009 |         1 |       100 |   100 |
| 353 |   4010 |         1 |       100 |   500 |
| 354 |   4011 |         1 |       100 |    50 |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

I want to create a diff between the column **value** groupped by source_id and target_id. The older one (smaller id) should be compared with the newer one

I have searched a little bit and found `coalesce`. I have written a small query and it works in "general", but not as expexted:

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.source_id, c.target_id, c.value, COALESCE(c1.value - c.value, -1) AS diff
FROM
    changes c LEFT JOIN changes c1 ON (c1.source_id = c.source_id AND c1.target_id = c.target_id)
GROUP BY c.source_id, c.target_id, c.job_id
ORDER BY c.id
```

I got following result:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+------+
| id  | source_id | target_id | value | diff |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+------+
| 204 |       247 |       228 |  1201 |    0 |
| 349 |       247 |       228 |   100 | 1101 |
| 350 |       247 |       228 |   500 |  701 |
| 351 |       247 |       228 |  1000 |  201 |
| 352 |         1 |       100 |   100 |    0 |
| 353 |         1 |       100 |   500 | -400 |
| 354 |         1 |       100 |    50 |   50 |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+------+
```

You can see the diff work for id 349 and 353, I want this for all rows like the following expected result:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+------+
| id  | source_id | target_id | value | diff |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+------+
| 204 |       247 |       228 |  1201 | 1201 |
| 349 |       247 |       228 |   100 | 1101 |
| 350 |       247 |       228 |   500 | -400 |
| 351 |       247 |       228 |  1000 | -500 |
| 352 |         1 |       100 |   100 |  100 |
| 353 |         1 |       100 |   500 | -400 |
| 354 |         1 |       100 |    50 |  450 |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+------+
```

It would be no problem if the diff result is inverted.

What did I miss?
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Plz be clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add that. I thought it was clear with the diff. I have added a sample expected output

Comment: For id 351 shouldn't the diff be -500, and for 352 be 900?

Comment: I haven't got the slightest clue what you are trying to do or why its even necessary can you clarify?

Comment: I hope it is more clear now. I just want to get the difference of value between each row. :)

Comment: I don't understand how the expected result relates to the data set. For instance (100,500)=-400 but (500,1000) = +500 How?

Comment: @Strawberry thats what I was sayin! it looks like the next row (with the bigger id) is supposed to subtract from the previous row.. but then theres the negatives that get switched which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Strawberry I think the diff 500 is a typo and should be -500.

Comment: how is 1101 - 500 equal to -400??

Comment: @JohnRuddell It isn't, the diff is the previous row's value - the row's value.. except for the first row of each group which is just the value. This is horrible logic imo, so I changed it to delta in my answer.

Comment: @Arth sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes it was a type, I have fixed it.

Comment: @Arth Do you have an idea to improve it? :)

Comment: Guys incredible how fast you are. Finally I have some "measures" (nothing real academic valid) about speed and indeed John's answer is the fastest, then Arth's solution which takes about the double of time and I am sorry on the last place Strawberry's one with nearly three times longer. But all of you are good! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use user defined variables you don't need to join the table to itself. just do a row by row comparrision like so

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  job_id, 
  target_id, 
  if(@a = source_id, @b - value, value) as diff, 
  @b := value as value, 
  @a := source_id as source_id 
FROM changes
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a:=0, @b:=0)t
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c17a/2)

Comment: +1 for succinct lushness, I know you like your @vars.

Comment: @Arth lol well my join method would just be a copy of yours.. so I have to have some 'originality' :P

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you're looking for something like this - although the COALESCE bit seems misleading to me...

```
SELECT a.*, COALESCE(b.value-a.value,a.value) diff
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.* , COUNT(*) rank FROM changes x JOIN  changes y ON y.id <= x.id GROUP BY x.id ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.* , COUNT(*) rank FROM changes x JOIN  changes y ON y.id <= x.id GROUP BY x.id ) b
    ON b.source_id = a.source_id
   AND b.rank = a.rank - 1;
```

Comment: Like it, a different approach to mine, wonder which is faster! I'm stealing your COALESCE btw for my addendum as it is way more readable.

Comment: Well, I think mine gives the correct result - so it might not win on the performance stakes, but... !  ;-)

Comment: Please explain how mine doesn't give the correct results (with addendum)

Comment: Nice, I like that you used a subquery in the FROM() cool way to do it. +1

Comment: So subqueries are the "normal" way to do it?

Comment: @CSchulz I'm pretty sure this question requires a subquery of some description. In this case pick whatever answer you are comfortable with, is the best performance or you find easiest to read. In any order you see fit.

Comment: @CSchulz i just threw in my answer for kicks arth answered first and then strawberry i would recommend you accept one of those two :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I think yours is the fastest, but I can't be sure, it certainly wins on code length.

Comment: I suspect John's is fastest too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
   SELECT c.id,
          c.source_id,
          c.target_id,
          c.value,
          c.value - COALESCE(co.value, 0) delta
     FROM changes c
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT ci.id, MAX(cio.id) prev_id
         FROM changes ci
         JOIN changes cio
           ON cio.source_id = ci.source_id 
          AND cio.target_id = ci.target_id
          AND cio.id < ci.id
     GROUP BY ci.id
          ) link
       ON link.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN changes co
       ON co.id = link.prev_id
 ORDER BY c.id
```

I have changed the logic slightly.

In your expected results, the first diff has gone from unknown (0?) to 1201 and is reported as a positive diff, but the second has gone from 1201 to 100 and is still reported as positive.

I have changed the name to delta, and given you the number required to move from the previous value to the new value. Obviously you can change this if you want to:

```
COALESCE(co.value-c.value, c.value) diff
```

which will get you the results you provided (with the diff 500 changed to -500, which I believe was a typo).

Comment: I dono about yall but im going to throw some +1's around :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Cheers. Targik is still waiting for his... :)

Comment: Targik didn't give an answer... that should have been a comment. if it provided a solution I would most definitely give a +1.. thats what were all on here for :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I know, I was being obtuse!

Comment: By mine and John's reckoning, the correct result should be [1201,1101,-400,-500,100,-400,450]. This gives [1201,-1101,400,500,100,400,-450], so something's wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I changed the logic to delta rather than diff for my main query.. it's all in the answer. Replacing the delta with the diff line in the addendum should produce the original results.